# Flutter: flutter_signin_button overflow issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am using [flutter_signin_button](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_signin_button) package to create Facebook and Apple Sign In buttons for login. However, I am facing overflow issue. Following is my code:

```
Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: SignInButton(
    Buttons.FacebookNew,
    onPressed: () => authBloc.loginFacebook(),
  ),
),
Container(
  child: SignInButton(
    Buttons.AppleDark,
    onPressed: () {},
    text: "Apple",
  ),
),
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
  child: Text("OR",
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: SizeConfig.textMultiplier * 2.2,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
),
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
),
Container(
  width: 205,
  child: ElevatedButton(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      primary: Color(0xFF1fd281),
    ),
    onPressed: () => authBloc.loginAnonymous(),
    child: Container(
      width: 190,
      child: Text(
        "Play As Guest",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

The output is in the image below:
[image]

I even tried the make the container full width in an attempt to remove this overflow, but still doesn't work. Facing this issue on iPhone 7 Plus only. Not facing this issue on iOS simulator.

As per suggestion by @Sachin Liyanage, I added Expanded and the output is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

no no Use a slivers with custom scrollview and set width via padding like

```
customScrollview(
slivers:[
SliverAppBar("yourAppBar"),
SliverPAdding(
padding: EdgeInsets.all(24) // give here padding for width you button 
sliver:SliverToBoxAdapter(
child: "YourButtton"
)
)
]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**: Use `Expanded` or `Flexible` as a parent of your `Container`

```
Expanded(
  child:Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: SignInButton(
      Buttons.FacebookNew,
      onPressed: () => authBloc.loginFacebook(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

**Solution 2**: Use `Card` like this, Change the following code according to your need.

```
Card(
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Image.asset('assets/fc-logo.png', width: 56, height: 56),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text("Flutter Clutter", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
              Text("Internationalization (i18n) in Flutter: an easy and quick approach")
            ]
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        Text("03.03.2020"),
      ]
    )
  )
);
```

For more ways refer to this - https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/troubleshooting/widget-overflowed-by-pixels/2020/461/

**Solution 3**: Use AutoSizeText widget for facebook text

Refer to this - https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

Comment: updated my question with an image of the output after expanded. As you can see the container is larger than the text even in the first scenario because of double.infinity. But still there is overflow error

Comment: @SaadBashir added 3rd solution, try it

Comment: can't use AutoSizeText because the package allows only text string and not a widget.